How would you know if this system is stable or not?
I'm having trouble deciding whether a system whose characteristic equation is
\$1200y''(t) + b·y'(t) + (1.02·10^6) y(t) = f(t)\$
(where \$f(t)\$ is a negative unit step that occurs between \$t=10\$ and \$t=20\$, or \$f(t)=-H(t-10) + H(t-20)\$ )
is stable for some values of \$b.\$
This gave me \$ Y(s)=\frac{-e^{-10s}+e^{-20s}}{1200s(s^2+\frac{b}{1200}s+850)} \$
In order to show that the limit of \$f(t)\$ when \$t→∞\$ goes to zero, I can use the final-value theorem showing that the limit of \$s·Y(s)\$ goes to zero when \$s→0\$, so long as the limit when \$t→∞\$ exists. I know also that I can show that all the poles of \$Y(s)\$ have their real part \$<0 \$ then the function \$f(t)\$ will have such a behaviour but I don't really know what to do if I should find that one of the poles is \$s=0\$. I think that once I antitransform the result should be something that, for \$t>20\$, will have two terms equal to each other and opposite in sign that will cancel out, and everything else will be multiplied by an exponential, but I'm not sure because I suppose I would have to assign actual values to \$b\$ to see if it ends up being stable or not.
Do the poles of the transform \$Y(s)\$ need to all have real part lower than zero or could it also happen that there are poles that are zero, so long as the term that has the denominator \$1/s\$ ends up cancelling out with something else when I antitransform? It seems weird to me because if that is the case then can I just say that \$b\$ needs to be just greater than zero?

The step response is called the index response. Given the transfer function of the system which is the Laplace transform of the impulse response, it is stable if its poles all have a negative real part. In this case the system is stable if b>0, in fact, if a0=1200, both real parts are equal to: -b/(2a0).

I think I finally understood it, thanks a bunch :)
